# Custom Labels in Summer 13 release

Tags: administration, customlabel

I cannot find where Salesforce is hiding the custom labels in Salesforce for Summer 13 version I have google and got this:

> From Setup, in Create | Custom Labels, click New Custom Label to
>   create a new label, or click Edit next to the custom label you want to
>   edit.

Create | Custom Labels does not exist...where is the new location?

Comment: I am looking at it right now. What kind of org are you looking at? DE? EE?

Comment: Unlimited Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup > Create > Custom Labels

You can also use the quick find in the setup menu to find items such as this in the complex web of the setup tree. It's worth noting that Custom Labels are only available in Professional Edition and above.

EDIT: a quick google search reveals that if your Salesforce instance was upgraded from a lesser edition that some features may not be turned on my default. In this case, you'd need to open a case with support.

Comment: Needed to open the case with Support to get it activated.